# Send Image over TCP in android applications

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I'm trying to make two android applications connected with TCP protocol.
Client has an imageView and when you push the button, it is supposed to send that image to the server and after server reads it, it is suppose to display the image.
but I haven't been able to display the sent image in server. 
somebody could please give me a hand?

THIS IS MY SERVER CODE THAT GETS THE IMAGE AND IT IS SUPPOSE TO DISPLAY IT

```
        package com.example.simpleserver;

    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

     public class SimpleServer extends Activity {
       ServerSocket ss = null;
       Thread myCommsThread = null;
       protected static final int MSG_ID = 0x1337;
       public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;
       private Bitmap bitmap;

       @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_server);
       TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView01);
       tv.setText("Nothing from client yet");
       this.myCommsThread = new Thread(new CommsThread());
       this.myCommsThread.start();
       }

       @Override
       protected void onStop() {
       super.onStop();
       try {
            // make sure you close the socket upon exiting
           ss.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }

       Handler myUpdateHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MSG_ID:
                     ImageView tv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewServer);
                     tv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                     break;
                   default:
                       break;
                   }
             super.handleMessage(msg);
         }
      };
       class CommsThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
           Socket s = null;
            try {
            ss = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            Message m = new Message();
            m.what = MSG_ID;

            try {
                if (s == null)
                    s = ss.accept();
                InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(in);

                int len = dis.readInt();
                byte[] data = new byte[len];
                if (len > 0) {
                    dis.readFully(data);
                }
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);
                myUpdateHandler.sendMessage(m);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

AND THIS IS MY CLIENT CODE THAT SENDS THE IMAGE

```
        package com.example.simpleclient;

    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class SimpleClient extends Activity {

        private Socket socket;

        private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
        private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_simple_client);        
            new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {;
                getBytes();

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        public void getBytes() throws IOException{
            ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            //convert the image to bitmap to be send in the intent
            Bitmap bmp=((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            int bytes = bmp.getByteCount();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); //Create a new buffer
            bmp.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); //Move the byte data to the buffer

            byte[] array = buffer.array(); 
            int start=0;
            int len=array.length;
            if (len < 0)
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative length not allowed");
            if (start < 0 || start >= array.length)
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Out of bounds: " + start);

            OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream(); 
            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);

            dos.writeInt(len);
            if (len > 0) {
                dos.write(array, start, len);
            }

        }

        class ClientThread implements Runnable {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Well how far does it come? Does the client connect? Is the bitmap sent? Is the bitmap received? You have to tell us. You could add some log statements so you see what is happening. No errors? Did you check the len sent and len received equal?

Comment: there's not problem with the connection and no errors displayed. the problem seems to be in server while trying to convert the received byte array into bitmap, I get bitmap empty. Does someone know the best way to convert byte array to bitmap?

Comment: Is len sent the same as len received? Why do i have to ask that twice?

Comment: Yes it is the same len in received. the problem seams to be here:`bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data .length);`

Comment: In your client you at last have the bitmap in byte[] array. Did you try to convert it -in your client- back immediately to a bitmap and display there in an ImageView? If you didn't then first try that. The way you converted a Bitmap to byte[] is diffrent from the one I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code to put your image in a byte array:

```
     ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
     Bitmap bmp=((BitmapDrawable)iv.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

     ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
     bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
     byte array [] = baos.toByteArray();
```

Further I must remark that you execute getBytes() on the main thread. This is only possible in older Android versions. Better put it in your thread.

Answer (score 7):

My code is now working. I'll post the code in case someone finds it helpful

SERVER

```
    package com.example.serverlate;
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.DataInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.net.ServerSocket;
    import java.net.Socket;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ServerLate extends Activity {

        private ServerSocket serverSocket;

        Handler updateConversationHandler;

        Thread serverThread = null;


        private ImageView imageView;//  private TextView text;

        public static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_late);


            imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewServer);//text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView01); 

            updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

            this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
            this.serverThread.start();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        class ServerThread implements Runnable {

            public void run() {
                Socket socket = null;
                try {
                    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVERPORT);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

                    try {

                        socket = serverSocket.accept();

                        CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                        new Thread(commThread).start();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        class CommunicationThread implements Runnable {

            private Socket clientSocket;

            private DataInputStream input;//private BufferedReader input;       

            public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

                this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

                try {

                    //this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                    InputStream in = this.clientSocket.getInputStream();
                    this.input = new DataInputStream(in);               

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            public void run() {
                System.out.println("hello");
                while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                    try {
                        byte[] data;//String read = input.readLine();
                        int len= this.input.readInt();                  
                        data = new byte[len];                   
                        if (len > 0) {
                            this.input.readFully(data,0,data.length);
                        }   
                        /*
                        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        byte[] data;
                        int length = 0;
                        while ((length = this.input.read(data))!=-1) {
                            out.write(data,0,length);
                        }
                           data=out.toByteArray();
                        */

                        updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(data));//updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(read));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
            private byte[] byteArray;//private String msg;

            public updateUIThread(byte[] array){    //public updateUIThread(String str) {
                this.byteArray=array;   //this.msg = str;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() { 
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray , 0, byteArray .length);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);//text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

CLIENT

```
    package com.example.clientlate;

    import java.io.BufferedWriter;
    import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
    import java.io.DataOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
    import java.io.PrintStream;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.InetAddress;
    import java.net.Socket;
    import java.net.UnknownHostException;
    import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
    import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    public class ClientLate extends Activity {

        private Socket socket;

        private static final int SERVERPORT = 5000;
        private static final String SERVER_IP = "10.0.2.2";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_late);      

            new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {
            try {           
                ImageView imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);//EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
                Bitmap bmp=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); //String str = et.getText().toString();

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
                bmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos); 
                byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();

                OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream(); 
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
                dos.writeInt(array.length);
                dos.write(array, 0, array.length);

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        class ClientThread implements Runnable {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: You are right, I corrected that. Excuse me , do you know how to retrieve the image but in a c++ server? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24541205/how-to-send-image-from-android-client-to-c-server-tcp

Comment: Had a quick look. So you want a TCP server running on Android? Written in QT C++?

Comment: NO, I have a client written in java running on android, an my server is in qt c++.

Comment: Thast is not an answer to my questions. Please reread carefully and answer to the point. Both questions can be answered with yes/no.