# Android: trouble to send bitmap byte array over socket

Tags: java, android, sockets

With relation to my [**last question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39005573/android-thread-not-is-initializing), i now have trouble to send `Bitmap` byte array for server side.

*Small explanation about this project example (the same of my previous question):*

> Server sends a string command requesting a screenshot to Client .apk, then if this specific string is received by Client, so Client executes a method called in my code below of `getBytes()` where this method is responsible for: 
>   Capture screenshot of device as Bitmap, Transform this Bitmap in a bytes array, Compress this bytes array using **ZLIB** library and finally sends this bytes array compressed to server side..

Apparently all seems ok, but nothing is received in server side.

```
package com.example.client;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.zip.Deflater;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Socket clientSocket;

    private static final int SERVERPORT = 60;
    private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.25.227";

    byte[] tmpbytes = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();

    }

        public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {

           View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
           rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
           return rootView.getDrawingCache();

        }

        ///////////////////////  ZLIB compression library. ////////////////////////////////

        public static byte[] compress(byte[] data) throws IOException {  

               Deflater deflater = new Deflater();  
               deflater.setInput(data);  
               ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);   
               deflater.finish();  
               byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];   
               while (!deflater.finished()) {  
                int count = deflater.deflate(buffer);   
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);   
               }  
               outputStream.close();  
               byte[] output = outputStream.toByteArray();  

               return output;

              }  

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        public void getBytes() throws IOException {

            try
            {

            Bitmap bitmap = takeScreenshot();


            int bytes = bitmap.getByteCount();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(bytes); 
            bitmap.copyPixelsToBuffer(buffer); 

            byte[] array = buffer.array();
            byte[] arrsmall = compress(array); // Compress

            boolean retval = Arrays.equals(arrsmall, tmpbytes);

            if (!retval)
            {

                OutputStream out = clientSocket.getOutputStream(); 
                DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
                dos.writeInt(arrsmall.length);
                dos.write(arrsmall, 0, arrsmall.length);
                dos.flush();

                tmpbytes = arrsmall;

            }

          }

            catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                //System.out.println(e.toString());
            } 

            catch (IOException e) {
                //System.out.println(e.toString());
            } 

            catch (Exception e1) {
                //Log.e("clients", e1.toString());
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println(e1.toString());
            }

        }

        class ClientThread implements Runnable { 

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                    clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

                    new Thread(new CommsThread()).start();

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    //Log.e("clients", e1.toString());
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println(e1.toString());
                } 

            }
        }


        class CommsThread implements Runnable {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {

                while(clientSocket.isConnected() && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){

                    //System.out.println("Waiting for server request");

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

                    String message = reader.readLine();

                    if(message != null && !message.trim().isEmpty()) {

                    System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);

                    if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("screen"))

                        getBytes();

                    }

                    reader.close();

                    //clientSocket.close();

                    if(message.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) break;

                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }
                System.out.println("Shutting down Socket!!");
                clientSocket.close();
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    //Log.e("clients", e1.toString());
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e1.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println(e1.toString());
                } 

            }

            }

}
```

*LogCat* below

**When apk is started:**

```
E        08-19 15:41:40.071: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(6421): Parent view is not a TextView

E        08-19 15:41:40.341: E/ION(6421): ION_IOC_CUSTOM_GET_CONFIG ioctl Failed. Use default
```

**Only when i close server, LogCat show that string command was rceived:**

```
I        08-19 15:42:20.350: I/System.out(6421): Message Received: screen

I        08-19 15:42:20.380: I/dalvikvm-heap(6421): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.888MB for 1536016-byte allocation

E        08-19 15:42:20.420: E/dalvikvm(6421): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=4194304, min=1048576, ut=568

E        08-19 15:42:20.440: E/dalvikvm(6421): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=6291456, min=1572864, ut=368

E        08-19 15:42:20.470: E/dalvikvm(6421): adjustAdaptiveCoef max=8388608, min=2097152, ut=256

I        08-19 15:42:20.630: I/System.out(6421): java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
```

Any suggestion here, will welcome. :-)

Comment: `if(command == "screen")`. You cannot compare strings like that in java. `if(command.equals("screen"))`.

Comment: @greenapps, thank you for your comment :-). This I already fix in my answer on last question, see.

Comment: You are referring to an old post with very bad code (if i can believe the comments there). Meanwhile you will have made your code better. So post the better code here.

Comment: @greenapps, okay, question edited :-)

Comment: `Apparently all seems ok,`. You should exactly tell what goes ok. Which statements are executed and which not. And if there are errors or exceptions you should post the LogCat. Also you should tell what the code should do. What the server does, what the client does. Tell your protocol. Do not expect us to find that out while reading your code. We want to know what your code does before we look into your code.

Comment: @greenapps, question edited again. If appear any other doubt, say me here.

Comment: Ok. Now you told us what should happen. But i asked you too what all happens and not happens. But that you did not tell. How far does the code flow we want to know. At which moment/statement things go wrong? When is that SocketExeption thrown? At wich statement. It is in the logcat. You should have posted some more lines only.

Comment: @greenapps, like you can see, client receives string command with success, the trouble is only in moment of send to server (simply nothing is received on server side), Logcat don't show clearly this erro and all Logs that comes i showed above.

This "send function" was adapted from answer of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268910/send-image-over-tcp-in-android-applications), look for **CLIENT** code. I also have tested this function that i have mirrored, but result is same (nothing is received on server).

Comment: `like you can see, client receives string command with success`. Where do i see that?

Comment: @greenapps, here on LogCat: `I        08-19 15:42:20.350: I/System.out(6421): Message Received: screen`

Comment: Who is printing that? I dont see code for it.

Comment: @greenapps, `class CommsThread`

Comment: Ok. Please next time name the statement. `System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);` You said `When i close server:`. So the client really receives that message when you close the server? That cannot be planned i suppose. Please explain.

Comment: @greenapps, sincerely, i send command from server, but LogCat show `Message Received: screen` and `Grow heap (frag case)...` only when i close server.exe (cutting the connection between client and server). Therefore, I think that client really receives string command sent by server.

Comment: Yes the client receives it. Indeed. But only if you kill the server. So why are you complaining that the server receives nothing? A killed server cannot receive anything isnt it? And of course you should have mentioned that before that the client only receives when you close the server. I even asked you to tell what happens and not happens.

Comment: @greenapps, in my opinion, the correct is to receive on moment that was requested by server and not after it. LogCat also can show `System.out` after?

Comment: Indeed. Completely true. But also correct would have been if you had told this all directly in your post. You are not even commenting on it.

Comment: @greenapps, i think that there something wrong with `while` loop on `class CommsThread`, what you think?

Comment: I think that you first should comment.

Comment: @greenapps, i made this now.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion, instead of using custom sockets and threads you could just try many of the http based dependencies like Volley or even Retrofit and just send the byte data as a multipart http request. it would be much easier and clearer. Or the server cannot communicate using HTTP?

Comment: server cannot communicate using http, Server.exe is done in Delphi and uses `TServerSocket` component. So, for be more easy for me, is better use Sockets in both (Client android and Server Delphi) :-). But thank you by your suggestion.