# Can I use getDrawable() with images from the gallery

Tags: android, image, tcp

I'm writing an android app where two devices have to exchange images from the gallery over tcp. My question is, to use getDrawable(), my image has to be in the Drawable folder? Or I can use the method with images from the phone's gallery? Thank u in advance for tour help. Please bear with me if the question is too silly or obvious, I'm just but a newbie.

Comment: ImageView imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageUpload);
  Bitmap bmp=((BitmapDrawable)imageUpload.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Comment: Please see my answer below. Hope it will help you to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you want to use image from `Drawable` folder, use `ContextCompat.getDrawable()`.

   ```
   ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageUpload);
   imageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.IMAGE_NAME));
   ```
2. If you want to pick and use image from gallery, use `Intent` with `ACTION_PICK`:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
   intent .setType("image/*");
   startActivityForResult(intent , REQUEST_CODE);
   ```
3. You will get image path `imageUri` from `Intent` in `onActivityResult()` method. Finally use `imageView.setImageBitmap()` to show `bitmap` on `ImageView`.

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
       super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

       if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
               try {
                   final Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                   final InputStream imageStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                   final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

                   imageView.setImageBitmap(selectedImage);
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

           }
       } 
   }
   ```

Don't forget to add permission in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**UPDATE:**

To send image over `TCP`, convert your `bitmap` to `byte array` and send using `SOCKET` with `DataOutputStream`:

```
.................
.........................
Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
selectedImage.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos); 
byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();

OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream(); 
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
dos.writeInt(array.length);
dos.write(array, 0, array.length);
............
...................
```

FYI, If you want to get `bitmap` from `imageView`. Try this:

> ```
> //Get bitmap from imageView 
> Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
> ```

For details: [Send Image over TCP in android applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268910/send-image-over-tcp-in-android-applications)

**Hope this will help~**

Comment: Thank u for your response, what i really want to do with the image is send it over tcp. When I use the second and third solution u gave, I can't manage to do that.

Comment: @Melo: To send image over `TCP`, convert your `bitmap` to `byte array` and send using `SOCKET` with `DataOutputStream`. Please check my updated answer.