# Sending a photo from a device using Python3 and receiving it on an Android Device via TCP gives an OOM on the Android Device

Tags: android, python-3.x, sockets, tcp, file-transfer

I am trying to send a photo from my Raspberry Pi using Python 3, to my Android Device. I am doing this over TCP with the Pi as the Client, and the Android Device as my Server. My goal is to send a photo file from Pi to my Android Device. My Android Device would then decode that photo data and then set it as the drawable for an ImageView in my App. Kindly note that I'm sending a 200kB image that's 640x480.

I have tried a set up where the Pi sends text to my Android Device via TCP, and I've had success with that.

What I did next was to attempt to send a photo from a Python3 client to a Python3 Server. In this case, I used the Pi still as my client, and I used my MacOS Laptop as the Server. This are the code that I ended up using.

### Server - MAC OS

```
import socket               # Import socket module

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
port = 11111                 # Reserve a port for your service.
s.bind((host, port))        # Bind to the port
f = open('torecv.jpg','wb')
s.listen(5)                 # Now wait for client connection.
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()     # Establish connection with client.
    print('Got connection from', addr)
    print("Receiving...")
    l = c.recv(1024)
    while (l):
        print("Receiving...")
        f.write(l)
        l = c.recv(1024)
    f.close()
    print("Done Receiving")
    c.send(b'Thank you for connecting')
    c.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    c.close()                # Close the connection
```

### Client - Pi

```
import socket               # Import socket module
import os

s = socket.socket()         # Create a socket object
host = socket.gethostname() # Get local machine name
host = '192.168.254.194' # Get local machine name

port = 6001                 # Reserve a port for your service.

CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()
PATH_TO_IMG_DIR = os.path.join(CWD_PATH, 'img_folder', 'test.jpg')

s.connect((host, port))


#s.send(b'Hello Server!')
f = open(PATH_TO_IMG_DIR,'rb')

print('Sending...')
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
    print('Sending...')
    s.send(l)
    l = f.read(1024)
f.close()
print("Done Sending")
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
print(s.recv(1024))
s.close                     # Close the socket when done
```

Using this code, I was able to transfer the photo from my Pi to my MacOS laptop.

Now, I used [the code here as reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268910/send-image-over-tcp-in-android-applications) in order to transfer my photo from my Pi to my Android Device. Now, this is my code:

### Server - Android

```
class ServerThread implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        Socket socket;
        try {
            Log.e(TAG, "starting the serverthread at port 6001");
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(6001);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception in creating server socket: ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();

                CommunicationThread commThread = new CommunicationThread(socket);
                new Thread(commThread).start();

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}


class CommunicationThread implements Runnable{
    private Socket clientSocket;

    private DataInputStream input;//private BufferedReader input;

    public CommunicationThread(Socket clientSocket) {

        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;

        try {
            Log.e(TAG, "getting data from the input stream!");
            //this.input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            InputStream in = this.clientSocket.getInputStream();
            this.input = new DataInputStream(in);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error in creating data input stream: ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        Log.e(TAG, "running the code!");
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            try {
                Log.e(TAG, "parsing the input data stream!");
                byte[] data;//String read = input.readLine();
                int len= this.input.readInt();

                if (len > 0) {
                    data = new byte[len];
                    this.input.readFully(data,0,data.length);
                }
                    /*
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] data;
                    int length = 0;
                    while ((length = this.input.read(data))!=-1) {
                        out.write(data,0,length);
                    }
                       data=out.toByteArray();
                    */

                Log.e(TAG, "Updating the UI through a thread!!");

//              updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(data));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e(TAG, "error in reading sent data! ", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in order to use these classes, I had declared the following as global variables:

```
Thread serverThread = null;
Handler updateConversationHandler;
```

And in my `onCreate()`, I have the following:

```
    updateConversationHandler = new Handler();

    this.serverThread = new Thread(new ServerThread());
    this.serverThread.start();
```

The app would start, and the socket would be opened. However, when I attempt to send in the photo from my Pi, I hit an error at this block of code:

```
public void run() {
    Log.e(TAG, "running the code!");
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        try {
            Log.e(TAG, "parsing the input data stream!");
            byte[] data;//String read = input.readLine();
            int len= this.input.readInt();

            if (len > 0) {
                data = new byte[len];
                this.input.readFully(data,0,data.length);
            }
                /*
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] data;
                int length = 0;
                while ((length = this.input.read(data))!=-1) {
                    out.write(data,0,length);
                }
                   data=out.toByteArray();
                */

            Log.e(TAG, "Updating the UI through a thread!!");

//          updateConversationHandler.post(new updateUIThread(data));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e(TAG, "error in reading sent data! ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

class updateUIThread implements Runnable {
    private byte[] byteArray;//private String msg;

    public updateUIThread(byte[] array){    //public updateUIThread(String str) {
        this.byteArray=array;   //this.msg = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.e(TAG, "running the photo update!");
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray , 0, byteArray .length);
        ivBed.setImageBitmap(bitmap);//text.setText(text.getText().toString()+"Client Says: "+ msg + "\n");
    }
}
```

Originally, the line:

```
data = new byte[len];
```

was outside the `if(len>0)` condition. But what happened was, for some reason, the Pi sent in a negative value, and of course we don't want a negative value for the `len` variable. Of course, I hit an error when I tried to create the byte array `data` with a negative length. I then put that line in the if condition.

However, after I did, I hit on OOM Error in the same line `data = new byte[len];`

```
Process: agict.work.freelance.patientsensor, PID: 15224
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1677608328 byte allocation with 6291456 free bytes and 254MB until OOM, max allowed footprint 7797480, growth limit 268435456
```

I have a hunch that in the 2nd error, I was trying to initialize the byte array with a value that was actually the image data already, hence, the OOM error.

However, if I just take in the first value and assign it as the `len`, there's a chance that I'd get a negative number and the code would hit the first error.

Would there be a chance that I have to tweak something in order to transfer a photo data from Python3 to Android? I have a feeling that there's a format mismatch of sorts that's happening.

Again, my goal is to send a photo file from Python3 to my Android Device via TCP. The Python3 will be given a file, and the Android Device will decode the input it gets, and once decoded, use that data as the drawable for an ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

According to me that error is caused by the size of the bitmap that you are trying to set for the `ImageView`. Checking sizes before use and/or scaling the bitmap may solve the issue. I've encountered such problems in the past before I start using third party libraries to load images.

You can take a look at this article from Android Developers and I think it can help:

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#java

Comment: My file is just a 196KB and is a 640x480 image.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. You're supposed to use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` Object.

```
class ServerImageThread implements Runnable{
    ServerSocket ss;
    Socket s;
    DataInputStream dis;

    byte[] data;

    @Override
    public void run(){
        try{
            ss = new ServerSocket(6001);

            while(true){
                s = ss.accept();
                InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
                dis = new DataInputStream(in);

                // read from the stream
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] content = new byte[1024];

                int bytesRead = -1;

                while( (bytesRead = in.read(content)) != -1 ) {
                    baos.write( content, 0, bytesRead );
                } // while

                Log.e(TAG, "made it through!");
                Log.e(TAG, "baos size is = " + baos.size());


                File file = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.jpg");

                FileOutputStream fos = null;
                try {
                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    baos.writeTo(fos);

                    Log.e(TAG, "managed to write baos to fos");

                } catch(IOException ioe) {
                    // Handle exception here
                    Log.e(TAG, "baos IOException = ", ioe);
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    Log.e(TAG, "closing fos");
                    fos.close();
                } 
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception in creating server socket: ", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You can call this via:

```
    Thread myThread = new Thread(new ServerImageThread());
    myThread.start();
```