# Send Image in Byte Array to server but it doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

My Server running on a PC and my Client running on an Android device.
My app in Android device work well, no crash or anything. The server didn't receive any thing so I don't know if the error come from which side.
Here is the **IndexControllerr** in PC's code:

```
public class IndexController extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public IndexController() {
    super();
}

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String fileNameLogoSchool = "Logodhbk.jpg";
    String fileNameLogoFac = "it.png";
    String fileName = "temporary_picture.jpg";
    
    request.setAttribute("fileNameLogoFac", fileNameLogoFac);
    request.setAttribute("fileNameLogoSchool", fileNameLogoSchool);
    request.setAttribute("fileName", fileName);
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/index.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
    
    try {
        
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1611);
        Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
        
        InputStream inputSocket = socket.getInputStream();
        
        while (true) {
            
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(inputSocket);
            
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg" ,new File("C:\\Users\\ASUS-PRO\\Downloads\\PBL4\\temporary_picture.jpg"));
            
            socket.close();
            serverSocket.close();
        }
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    
}
```

And here is the **Sendtring.java** in Android's code:

```
public class SendString extends EasyPaint {

private Socket socket;
private static final int SERVER_PORT = 1611;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.5";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}

public void uploadImage() {
    try {
        File file = new File(Places.getScreenshotFolder(), "temporary_picture.jpg");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(String.valueOf(file));

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
        byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();

        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(out);
        dos.writeInt(array.length);
        dos.write(array, 0, array.length);

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any answer would help, thanks for reading my question.

Comment: String.valueof(file) is definitely not what you wanna call. Get the debugger an see what its output is and you know what I mean.

Comment: Try upload that `byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("some.jpg"));`

Comment: Thank you i will try it right now

Comment: You can just read all the bytes and write that file exactly as it is on the other site. No need to do anything related to images, unless you want to reduce the quality on the way

Comment: Anything seems wrong in my Server's code?

Comment: I think it should be fine. But as I said in theory there is no need to actually do anything with images. `Files.write(Paths.get("your.jpg"),inputStream.readAllBytes());` just writes the bytes to the disk.

Comment: `byte[] b = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("your.jpg"));
        dataOutputStream.write(b, 0, b.length);`

Comment: Like that you would only transfer bytes. I mean I guess you are just trying out as far as I can tell

Comment: i tried but it still doesn't work, btw i follow the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268910/send-image-over-tcp-in-android-applications Hope you can check it, thanks.

Comment: Are you calling `uploadImage()` in a thread? You should. Does your client connect?

Comment: `dos.writeInt(array.length);` Please explain why you need this statement.